# loop through a file 4 rows at the time and store the lines in 4 variables

Tags: linux, bash, for-loop, while-loop, ksh

I'm trying to loop through a file 4 rows at the time  and store the lines in 4 variables

**Source**

```
8069347
41301052
394971301
39413010
8655766
91557668
754318656682
0279628
```

**Desired Output** stores the first 4 rows and after 5s the next 4 rows

```
8069347
41301052
394971301
39413010
```

> I tried this but it only stores the line  in `$a` and nothing in `$b`,`$c`,`$d`

```
while read -r a b c d ; do
    echo "$a"
    echo "$b"
    echo "$c"
    echo "$d"
    sleep 5
done < Auto
```

Any idea how to fix this?
I'm not opposed to a for-loop option

Comment: what is the desired output?

Comment: `while read -r a && read -r b && read -r c && read -r d; do`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to read 4 lines, you need to use the `read` command 4 times:

```
while read -r a; read -r b; read -r c; read -r d ; do
    echo "$a"
    echo "$b"
    echo "$c"
    echo "$d"
    sleep 5
done < Auto
```

Answer (score 1):

With 4 `read` commands:

```
{ read -r a; read -r b; read -r c; read -r d ;} < file
```

---

With a `for` loop and an array:

```
for((i=0; i<4; i++)); do read -r array[$i]; done < file
declare -p array
```

Output:

```
declare -a array=([0]="8069347" [1]="41301052" [2]="394971301" [3]="39413010")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use bash's `mapfile` to populate an array 4 lines/element at a time, instead of a bunch of `read`'s:

```
while mapfile -t -n 4 lines; do
    if [[ ${#lines[@]} -eq 0 ]]; then
        break
    fi
    printf "%s\n" "${lines[@]}"
    sleep 5
done < Auto
```